# Random forest only predicting one kind of class in tidymodels

Tags: r, random-forest

I have the following code:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)


olympics <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-07-27/olympics.csv')


olympics <- olympics %>%
  drop_na()

olympics %>%
  filter(medal == "Gold") %>%
  group_by(team, medal) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  top_n(10, n)


olympics <- olympics %>%
  select(sex, age, height, weight, year, season, sport, medal)


split      <- initial_split(olympics)
train_data <- training(split)
test_data  <- testing(split)


prep_recipe <- recipe(medal ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric())  %>%
  step_zv(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  prep()


training_preproc <- juice(prep_recipe)
testing_preproc  <- bake(prep_recipe, test_data)


training_preproc %>% 
  count(medal)

#-----

dt_spec <- rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")


fdt_fitted <- dt_spec %>% 
  fit(medal ~ ., data = training_preproc) #entra l'especificacio


predict(dt_fitted, training_preproc) %>% 
  count(.pred_class)


predict(dt_fitted, training_preproc) %>% 
  bind_cols(training_preproc$medal) %>% 
  mutate(correct = ifelse(.pred_class == ...2, 1, 0)) %>% 
  summarize(sum(correct))


nrow(training_preproc)
```

The random forest spec is giving me the following output:

```
1) root 22635 15003 Bronze (0.3371769 0.3354539 0.3273691)
```

Basically, giving only `Bronze` to everything. However, counting the number of medals in the training dataset, I get

```
  medal      n
  <fct>  <int>
1 Bronze  7632
2 Gold    7593
3 Silver  7410
```

So I don't know why is giving me these poor predictions, maybe I'm doing something wrong here? If the number of Bronze was much greater than the other classes I could understand it, but with these results I can't.

Comment: Tune the hyper-parameters.

Comment: You are making the common mistake of trying to create a decision machine (aka classifier) rather than a prediction machine.  Once you realize that the task is to accurately estimate probabilities you will not encounter such anomalies.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Could you please elaborate? I still don't get it

Comment: @Sycorax I tried modifying `trees` and `min_n` in the specification, but it gives the same result

Comment: Try more? You'll need to vary the hyper-parameters in combination over a wide range of values. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344220/how-to-tune-hyperparameters-in-a-random-forest More results in a search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+forest+tune Note that you don't need to tune the number of trees, just choose a number of trees that's "large enough."  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348245/do-we-have-to-tune-the-number-of-trees-in-a-random-forest?r=SearchResults&s=5|77.1587

Comment: Try using `randomForest` package and see whether it gives you the desired output